# As3 application on android tablet playing mp4 video doesn't pause correctly?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe, flashdevelop

When i run my application on the tablet(android) and hit the pause button it pauses the screen of the video but the video will jump a head how ever many seconds the pause when i un-pause the video. So if i start the video and then click pause and walk away i can come back and un-pause the video and it well jump right to the end.

The code i am using is  `ns.togglePause();` This same code works on the desktop and works with .flv and .f4v but will not work when i am using a mp4 on the tablet.

Has anyone seen this before or know why it would do something like this?

i am using flashdevelop to debug the application.

Comment: You might specify which version of AIR you're using and which Android device. If possible try a different model of Android device. When you pause, the default behavior is that Flash will continue to buffer the stream - so it's sort of doing half of it correctly. You might try using the `pause()` and `resume()` methods (shot in the dark), and play with the `bufferLength` property of `NetStream`. Note there are some interesting comments in the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#pause()) for `pause()` regarding `bufferLength`.

Comment: Sorry, `bufferLength` is read only... I should have suggested playing with the `bufferTime` property (set it to 1 or 0, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your help Sunil! So on the tablet i have has air 3.5.0.1060. I will start playing around with the setting you suggested and reply back.

Comment: So i have a little more information when i track the time `ns.time()` the video is pausing. I get the same amount of of seconds back when i pause as when i resume but it is skipping a head after that point so if i pause it again the time will be way ahead for where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my problem is caused by encoding. This helped me solve my problem.I found this on adobes forms.

Video encoding is very important.
For example, use baseline profile level 3.1 for H264 for mobile
(and not High profile level 4.1 recommended for desktop).
For more information, see the MAX session of Fabio Sonnati:
"Encoding for Performance on Multiple Devices"
And if you have an Android phone/tablet, there is my AIR application
to watch Adobe MAX 2011 videos :
https://market.android.com/details?id=air.fr.inway.maxVideos2011
Search "Sonnati" for this session's video.
(For info, i use a video player based on OSMF 1.6)

The pdf presentation is available on Sonmati's blog:
http://sonnati.wordpress.com/